# Why does I get the error "error undefine 'http....' is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-theme="b" data-role="button" onclick="proceed()" >Proceed</a></div>
```

```
   function proceed() 
   {
       window.location.href("CreditCard.aspx");
   }
```

Hello guys i tested this code on my local server and it can work but however i tested this on the mobile server. It throws back an error undefine 'http....' is not a function

Comment: Doesn't it say `href is not a function`?

Comment: nope it just say http'...' is not a function

Answer (score 4):

`window.location.href` is a string, not a function.

Assign a value to it with `=`

```
function proceed() {
   location.href = "CreditCard.aspx";
}
```

Although, in this case, you shouldn't. There is no need to involve JavaScript in this.

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
    <a href="CreditCard.aspx" data-theme="b" data-role="button">
        Proceed
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Window.location accepts a string. as you are making as a function , check the MDN for documentation [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

```
function proceed()       
{
   window.location.href="CreditCard.aspx"; // change like this 
}
```